# Inserting XML data into MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, xml, saxparser, taverna

I am trying to insert XML data into a MySQL database.  The SAX parser I wrote works on its own when tested.  However, whenever I try to insert records into the database, I get a NullPointerException even though I made sure to assign values to workflow elements that were null.  Here is my database Table code.
    package database;

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;

public class Table {
// JDBC driver name and database URL
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://baldwin.isri.cmu.edu/SciSIP";

//  Database credentials
static final String USER = "user";
static final String PASS = "pass";

public Table()  {

}

public void createTable()  {    
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try{
        //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //STEP 3: Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

        //STEP 4: Execute a query
        System.out.println("Creating table in given database...");
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS workflow" +
                "(id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                " annotationBean VARCHAR(255), " + 
                " date VARCHAR(255), " + 
                " text VARCHAR(255), " +
                " identification VARCHAR(255), " +
                " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))"; 

        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("Created table in given database...");
    } catch(SQLException se) {
        //Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //finally block used to close resources
        try {
            if(stmt != null)
                con.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
        }// do nothing
        try {
            if(con != null)
                con.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }//end finally try
    }//end try
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}

public void insertRecord(String annotationBean, String date, String text, String identification)  {
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //Load the driver           
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO `workflow` VALUES ('"+annotationBean+"', '"+date+"', '"+text+"', '"+identification+"')";
        stmt.execute(sql); //Insert a row
        System.out.println("Record Inserted into Database...");
    } catch(SQLException se) {
        //Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //finally block used to close resources
        try {
            if(stmt != null)
                con.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
        }// do nothing
        try {
            if(con != null)
                con.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }//end finally try
    }//end try
}
```

Here is my parser code with the insert record statement.

```
package parser;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import database.Table;

public class XML_Parser_SAX extends DefaultHandler{
List aWorkflow;
private String tempVal;
//to maintain context
private Workflow tempWorkflow;

public XML_Parser_SAX(){
    aWorkflow = new ArrayList();
}

public void runExample() {
    parseDocument();
    printData();
}

private void parseDocument() {
    //get a factory
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        //get a new instance of parser
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

        //parse the file and also register this class for call backs
        sp.parse("workflow.xml", this);

    }catch(SAXException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Iterate through the list and print
 * the contents
 */
private void printData(){

    System.out.println("Number of Tasks in Workflow: '" + aWorkflow.size() + "'.");

    Iterator it = aWorkflow.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next().toString());
    }
}


//Event Handlers
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    //reset
    tempVal = "";
    if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("annotationBean")) {
        //create a new instance of employee
        tempWorkflow = new Workflow();
        tempWorkflow.setAnnotationBean(attributes.getValue("class"));
        System.out.println("class");
    }
}


public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    tempVal = new String(ch,start,length);
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("annotationBean")) {
        //add it to the list
        aWorkflow.add(tempWorkflow);
        System.out.println("annotationBean");

    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("date")) {
        if (tempVal != null)  {
            tempWorkflow.setDate(tempVal);
        }
        else  {
            tempWorkflow.setDate("null");
        }
        System.out.println(tempWorkflow.getDate());
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
        if (tempVal != null)  {
            tempWorkflow.setText(tempVal);
        }
        else  {
            tempWorkflow.setText("null");
        }
        System.out.println(tempWorkflow.getText());
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("identification")) {
        if (tempVal != null)  {
            tempWorkflow.setIdentification(tempVal);
        }
        else  {
            tempWorkflow.setIdentification("null");
        }
        System.out.println(tempWorkflow.getIdentification());
    }
    Table t = new Table();
    //t.createTable();
    t.insertRecord(tempWorkflow.getAnnotationBean(), tempWorkflow.getDate(), tempWorkflow.getText(), tempWorkflow.getIdentification());
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    XML_Parser_SAX parse = new XML_Parser_SAX();
    parse.runExample();
}

}
```

Can someone please tell me why this is giving me the NullPointerException?  Thanks in advance!!!

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at parser.XML_Parser_SAX.endElement(XML_Parser_SAX.java:126)
at     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1741)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2898)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:274)
at parser.XML_Parser_SAX.parseDocument(XML_Parser_SAX.java:49)
at parser.XML_Parser_SAX.runExample(XML_Parser_SAX.java:35)
at parser.XML_Parser_SAX.main(XML_Parser_SAX.java:131)
```

Yes, workflow.xml exists.  Here is a copy of it below.

```
<workflow xmlns="http://taverna.sf.net/2008/xml/t2flow" version="1" producedBy="taverna-      2.4.0"><dataflow id="8781d5f4-d0ba-48a8-a1d1-14281bd8a917" role="top"><name>Hello_World</name>       <inputPorts /><outputPorts><port><name>greeting</name><annotations /></port></outputPorts>       <processors><processor><name>hello</name><inputPorts /><outputPorts><port><name>value</name>       <depth>0</depth><granularDepth>0</granularDepth></port></outputPorts><annotations />       <activities><activity><raven><group>net.sf.taverna.t2.activities</group>      <artifact>stringconstant-activity</artifact><version>1.4</version></raven>     <class>net.sf.taverna.t2.activities.stringconstant.StringConstantActivity</class><inputMap />    <outputMap><map from="value" to="value" /></outputMap><configBean encoding="xstream">    <net.sf.taverna.t2.activities.stringconstant.StringConstantConfigurationBean xmlns="">
  <value>Hello, World!</value>
 </net.sf.taverna.t2.activities.stringconstant.StringConstantConfigurationBean></configBean>    <annotations /></activity></activities><dispatchStack><dispatchLayer><raven>        <group>net.sf.taverna.t2.core</group><artifact>workflowmodel-impl</artifact>        <version>1.4</version></raven>       <class>net.sf.taverna.t2.workflowmodel.processor.dispatch.layers.Parallelize</class>        <configBean encoding="xstream">        <net.sf.taverna.t2.workflowmodel.processor.dispatch.layers.ParallelizeConfig xmlns="">
  <maxJobs>1</maxJobs>
    </net.sf.taverna.t2.workflowmodel.processor.dispatch.layers.ParallelizeConfig>    </configBean></dispatchLayer><dispatchLayer><raven><group>net.sf.taverna.t2.core</group>    <artifact>workflowmodel-impl</artifact><version>1.4</version></raven>    <class>net.sf.taverna.t2.workflowmodel.processor.dispatch.layers.ErrorBounce</class>    <configBean encoding="xstream"><null xmlns="" /></configBean></dispatchLayer><dispatchLayer>    <raven><group>net.sf.taverna.t2.core</group><artifact>workflowmodel-impl</artifact>    <version>1.4</version></raven>    <class>net.sf.taverna.t2.workflowmodel.processor.dispatch.layers.Failover</class><configBean     encoding="xstream"><null xmlns="" /></configBean></dispatchLayer><dispatchLayer><raven>    <group>net.sf.taverna.t2.core</group><artifact>workflowmodel-impl</artifact>    <version>1.4</version></raven>    <class>net.sf.taverna.t2.workflowmodel.processor.dispatch.layers.Retry</class><configBean     encoding="xstream"><net.sf.taverna.t2.workflowmodel.processor.dispatch.layers.RetryConfig     xmlns="">
  <backoffFactor>1.0</backoffFactor>
  <initialDelay>1000</initialDelay>
  <maxDelay>5000</maxDelay>
  <maxRetries>0</maxRetries>
</net.sf.taverna.t2.workflowmodel.processor.dispatch.layers.RetryConfig></configBean>    </dispatchLayer><dispatchLayer><raven><group>net.sf.taverna.t2.core</group>        <artifact>workflowmodel-impl</artifact><version>1.4</version></raven>        <class>net.sf.taverna.t2.workflowmodel.processor.dispatch.layers.Invoke</class><configBean         encoding="xstream"><null xmlns="" /></configBean></dispatchLayer></dispatchStack>       <iterationStrategyStack><iteration><strategy /></iteration></iterationStrategyStack>         </processor></processors><conditions /><datalinks><datalink><sink type="dataflow">        <port>greeting</port></sink><source type="processor"><processor>hello</processor>       <port>value</port></source></datalink></datalinks><annotations><annotation_chain         encoding="xstream"><net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.AnnotationChainImpl xmlns="">
  <annotationAssertions>
     <net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.AnnotationAssertionImpl>
       <annotationBean class="net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.annotationbeans.Author">
        <text>Stian Soiland-Reyes</text>
       </annotationBean>
       <date>2012-01-03 15:10:48.73 GMT</date>
      <creators />
       <curationEventList />
     </net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.AnnotationAssertionImpl>
  </annotationAssertions>
 </net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.AnnotationChainImpl></annotation_chain><annotation_chain     encoding="xstream"><net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.AnnotationChainImpl xmlns="">
   <annotationAssertions>
     <net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.AnnotationAssertionImpl>
      <annotationBean      class="net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.annotationbeans.DescriptiveTitle">
         <text>Hello World</text>
       </annotationBean>
           <date>2012-01-03 15:10:54.167 GMT</date>
       <creators />
  <curationEventList />
     </net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.AnnotationAssertionImpl>
  </annotationAssertions>
     </net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.AnnotationChainImpl></annotation_chain>            <annotation_chain_2_2 encoding="xstream"><net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.AnnotationChainImpl        xmlns="">
  <annotationAssertions>
    <net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.AnnotationAssertionImpl>
      <annotationBean     class="net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.annotationbeans.IdentificationAssertion">
        <identification>8781d5f4-d0ba-48a8-a1d1-14281bd8a917</identification>
      </annotationBean>
      <date>2012-01-03 15:12:21.684 GMT</date>
  <creators />
  <curationEventList />
</net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.AnnotationAssertionImpl>
```

```
<text>One of the simplest workflows possible. No workflow input ports, a         single          workflow output port "greeting",  outputting "Hello, world!" as produced by the        String          Constant "hello".</text>
                </annotationBean>
            <date>2012-01-03 15:12:15.643 GMT</date>
           <creators />
           <curationEventList />
        </net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.AnnotationAssertionImpl>
      </annotationAssertions>
       </net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.AnnotationChainImpl></annotation_chain></annotations >         
 </dataflow></workflow>
```

Comment: Can you please post stacktrace?

Comment: does workflow.xml exists ?

Comment: What's on line 126? (The source you posted is only 123 lines long)

Comment: Line 126 is "t.insertRecord(tempWorkflow.getAnnotationBean(), tempWorkflow.getDate(), tempWorkflow.getText(), tempWorkflow.getIdentification());"

Comment: I erased some whitespace when I copied and pasted, which in retrospect was a very bad idea.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `tempWorkflow` is set to null.

Your `startElement` only builds a tempWorkflow when it gets an `annotationBean` startTag, but it executes your failing element on ANY end tag. So when it gets `</configBean>` it will fail.

You need to have corresponding start and end actions =you have to add a lot more start actions. And you also have to check that everythingis properly initialized at the right places.

It will help a lot if you put in logging statements (e.g. log4J) such as:

```
LOG.debug("start-tag tempWorkFlow");
```

This will allow you to work out exactly when the code is being called.

Comment: I only want the 4 elements annotationBean, date, text, and identification.  I want to dump all the other data from the xml file, so how can I set it up so it only saves those elements in the database?  I will try adding the log4j statements as well and see if that helps.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to trap the start and end of every element your are interested in even if it's a no-op (then you can log it). You are creating a Table for EVERY end element.My guess is that this should only come in startDocument. And you probably need to add the record when you end the element net.sf.taverna.t2.annotation.AnnotationChainImpl. You need to work on your logic - it will come right if you work carefully