# Insert 5000 rows into MySQL and MongoDB

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb

I need to insert data similar to the XML object's below, up to 5000 times in both MySQL and MongoDB.
The data type can be HTML,Excel,XML and CSV as I am using a automatic test data generation tool.

```
<record>
<ID>1</ID>
<Email>rhoncus.Nullam.velit@sem.edu</Email>
<DOB>18/09/2012</DOB>
<Name> sapien</Name>
</record>
<record>
<ID>2</ID>
<Email>quam@penatibusetmagnis.edu</Email>
<DOB>26/05/2012</DOB>
<Name>ac</Name>
</record>
```

Is there a simple way of doing/triggering this for each database from java? 
Or is [Inserting XML data into MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894036/inserting-xml-data-into-mysql-database) the only way? (seems like hassle to set up for a one off insert of random data)

Comment: I would edit your question and take those passwords out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both mysql and mongo have many libraries that make this pretty simple to do.. If you're going to be parsing input data from all of these sources I would create a little pogo to hold the parsed data and then just write a method to send the data to each database... not really any shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the files to CSV and use [the answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605765/importing-a-csv-into-mysql-via-command-line) and Bob's your uncle... If you need further code as to how you convert XML, Excel, HTML to CSV, leave a comment under this answer.